# How do we include native library symbols for android app?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-ndk, crashlytics

in firebase crashlytics we see no stacktrace for native crash

[image]

How do we include symbol files?

Below is my guess on how to proceed..

1. build NDK from source and generate `*.so` files. They are typically generated under `obj` or `libs` folder.
2. find the path of the `*.so` files
3. direct crashlytics to upload those symbols using `firebaseCrashlytics` directive in `build.gradle` (https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/ndk-reports)

I'm not sure if my assumption is correct, if it is.. How do I do #1? build NDK?

I can see that react-native can generate those `*.so` files when I build react-native from source files. (such as libc++_shared.so)

I guess we need to do the same thing as RN is doing.

Comment: Take this with a grain of salt (I have never used crashlytics). I think the problem isn't that the stacktrace is missing because of no symbols but the stacktrace got overwritten (corrupted). I don't think there's a way to get any more info :(